# fullcalendar.io multiple eventsources in one feed

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar it is possible to define multiple feeds

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [
        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed1',
            color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
            url: '/myfeed2',
            color: 'red'
        }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to define multiple sources in one json feed?

I'm aiming for something like this:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
         eventSources: '/multiplefeedsineone'
     });
```

"Multiplefeedsinone" would return:

```
{
    events: [
        {
            title: 'EventFromFeed1_1',
            start: '2011-04-04'
        },
        {
            title: 'EventFromFeed1_2',
            start: '2011-05-05'
        }
    ],
    color: 'yellow'
},
{
    events: [
        {
            title: 'EventFromFeed2_1',
            start: '2011-04-04'
        },
        {
            title: 'EventFromFeed2_2',
            start: '2011-05-05'
        }
    ],
    color: 'red'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a single source URL, [an `events` object is passed instead of an `eventSources` object.](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#options)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            custom_param1: 'something',
            custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }

});
```

You may not pass `color` and `textColor` options and in your backend *aggregate* multiple feeds. Results from your backend should be similar to this:

```
[
  {
    title: 'event1',
    start: '2010-01-01',
    color: 'yellow', 
  },
  {
    title: 'event1',
    start: '2010-01-01',
    color: 'red', 
  }
]
```

Comment: This way I get again one feed of all events (all yellow events).
I want to get the different feeds in one request to get all my red and all my yellow events in one request (and set the color from the backend)

Comment: I could indeed set the color per event. (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)